# Proving that $I_{n}+\lambda C^{T}C$ is a positive defined matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the matrix $A=I_{n}+\lambda C^{T}C$ is positive defined (PD) for $\lambda >0$ and some $C_{n\times m}$. I have already proved that the matrix $A$ is symmeric and of order $n\times n$. I'm trying to prove that for every $\underline{x}\neq 0$ we get $\underline{x}^T A\underline{x}>0$.
I get:

$$
\underline{x}^T A\underline{x}=\underline{x}^T\left(I_{n}+\lambda C^{T}C\right)\underline{x}=I_n+\underline{x}^T\lambda C^{T}C\underline{x}
$$
But how should I procced?

Comment: Your final expression should not be $I_n+\underline{x}^T\lambda C^{T}C\underline{x}$, it should be $\color{blue}{\underline{x}^T\underline{x}}+\underline{x}^T\lambda C^{T}C\underline{x}$. Now recall that $\underline{x}^T C^{T}C\underline{x} = \left\| C\underline{x}\right\|^{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $A$ is the sum of the positive defined matrix $I_n$ and the positive semi-defined matrix $C^TC$, therefore $A$ is positive defined.

$C^TC$ is always positive semi-defined because:

$$\underline{x}^T C^T C\underline{x} = (C\underline{x})^T (C\underline{x}) = \|C\underline{x}\|^2 \geq 0$$

for each $\underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Is it true to say $\underline{x}^{T}\underline{x}=||I_n \underline{x}||^2>0$?

Comment: Yes, if $\underline{x} \neq \underline{0}$ of course.